# Solve: $t\ddot{x}+\dot{x}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To solve the above mentioned equation I used a substitution $u=\dot{x}$. Thus I now have $t\dot{u}+u=0 \rightarrow \dot{u} = -\frac{1}{t}u \rightarrow \int\frac{1}{u}du = -\int\frac{1}{t}dt \rightarrow ln(u) = -ln(t) + C$. This is where I got stuck, can someone point out if something went wrong or help me continue.

Comment: Take an exponent of the both parts.

Comment: Then I would get $u = -Ct$ right after some basic algebra.

Comment: Notice, there is minus sign in exponent.

Comment: Yes small mistake, then I would have $u= \frac{C}{t}$.

Comment: Now you can solve the D.E.

Comment: Thank you I found it!!